# Solving a system with $n$ unknown coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica, I have the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*", Subscript]

n = 5; P = 0; 
F = 1 + Sum[Subscript[c, i] x^i, {i, 1, n}];
R = D[F, x] - F - P; 
Do[S[i_] := Integrate[R D[R, Subscript[c, i]] /. x -> t, {t, 0, 1}], {i, 1, n}]
NSolve[{S[i] == 0}, {Subscript[c, i] ,{i, 1, n}}, Reals] /. Rule -> Set
Expand[F]
```

My problem is with the step of solving the system; it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the `S` with

```
Do[S[i] = Integrate[R*D[R, Subscript[c, i]], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1, n}]
```

(notice that there's no underscore after the `i`)
and then solve the equations with

```
Solve[Table[S[i] == 0, {i, n}], Table[Subscript[c, i], {i, n}]] /. Rule -> Set
```

Comment: Dear Roman, many thanks you solved my problem...Best regards